# How to keep a watermark at the background of a web page?

Tags: html, css, image, watermark

I am a pega developer never spend a lot of time in working on webpage.I want to create a pdf .In Pega that will be created from a html page.i need to keep the wate mark draft as background?

I tried following code but when im including it in my code it is creating as separate div and next divs are coming on the next page?and also the draft is not coming in the background middle ?`

```html
<div style="position:absolute;z-index:0;background:white;display:block;min-height:50%; min-width:50%;color:yellow;">

<p style="color:steelblue;font-size:120px;">DRAFT</p>
</div>
```

`

Comment: and keep width and height 100vh to keep the image over whole page, and also provide background-position: center; and background-size: contain; and your watermark will be ready

Comment: this is basic try considering this https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_text.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is another way. hope this helps

```css
div{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    background: white;
    display: block;
    min-height: 40%;
    min-width: 100%;
    color: yellow;
    border: 2px solid black;
    height: 200px;
}

p{margin:0}

div:after{
    content: "DRAFT";
    color: steelblue;
    font-size: 120px;
    /* text-align: center; */
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    opacity:0.1
}
```

```html
<div >


</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting a `background-image` in the CSS

```
body {
  background-image: url('https://example.com/image.jpg');
}
```

or in the HTML as so

```
<body style="background-image: url('https://example.com/image.jpg');">
```

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS to give the body the background:

```
body{
  background-image: url('../watermark.png');
  background-size: contain; /* Make background take entire page */
  background-position: center; /* Center Background */
}
```